# How to insert file content after a certain string in a file?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed, perl

we have for example this file

```
cat exam.txt

I am expert linux man
what we can do for out country
I love redhat machine
"propertie"
centos less then redhat
fedore what
my name is moon yea
```

we want to add the content of any file as file.txt after properties line

```
cat file.txt

324325
5326436
3245235
646346
545
643
6436
63525
664
46454
```

so I try the following:

```
a=` cat file `

sed -i '/propertie/a  `echo "$a"` ' exam.txt
```

but not works

any suggestion with sed/awk/perl one liner in order to add content of file after  certain string?

expected output

```
I am expert linux man
what we can do for out country
I love redhat machine
"propertie"
    324325
    5326436
    3245235
    646346
    545
    643
    6436
    63525
    664
    46454
centos less then redhat
fedore what
my name is moon yea
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You almost never want to store the complete contents of a file in a variable in a Unix shell script.  If you find yourself doing that, ask yourself whether there's another solution.  If you can't find one on your own, come here and we'll look at it :-)

---

```
$ sed '/propertie/r file.txt' exam.txt
I am expert linux man
what we can do for out country
I love redhat machine
"propertie"
324325
5326436
3245235
646346
545
643
6436
63525
664
46454
centos less then redhat
fedore what
my name is moon yea
```

The `r` ("read") command in `sed` takes a filename as its argument and inserts the file's content into the current stream.

If you need the added content indented, then make sure that the content of `file.txt` is indented before running `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/^/    /' file.txt >file-ind.txt
$ sed '/propertie/r file-ind.txt' exam.txt
I am expert linux man
what we can do for out country
I love redhat machine
"propertie"
    324325
    5326436
    3245235
    646346
    545
    643
    6436
    63525
    664
    46454
centos less then redhat
fedore what
my name is moon yea
```

---

With `ed` (calling `sed` for the indentation of the inserted file).  This also does in-place editing of the file and replaces the original with the modified contents.

```
ed -s exam.txt <<END_ED
/propertie/r !sed 's/^/    /' file.txt
wq
END_ED
```

The `r` command in `ed` is able to read the output of an external command if the command is prefixed with `!`.  We use this to indent the data that we'd like to insert.  It is otherwise, for obvious reasons, very similar to the `sed` solution above.

The only downside with using `ed` is that you can't generally use it on very large files.  `sed` is for editing streams of undetermined lengths, while `ed` is ok for editing documents that you could see yourself opening in any other editor, i.e. not files of many megabytes or gigabytes in size.

Comment: I am also up-vote , great answer and fast answer

Comment: @JeffSchaller Look again.

Comment: Upvoted twice! :)

Comment: i prefer the approach that uses `ed` because i could use an interpolated variable kind of like this, but couldn't do it with `sed` approach 
`ed -s /opt/${FOLDER}/exam.txt <<END_ED /propertie/r !sed 's/^/    /' file.txt wq END_ED`